# Is it possible to simplify linear regression if one of the variables does not have errors and is equispaced?

Tags: regression, time-series

Specifically, I have a time series with fixed $\Delta t$ of the following form:
$x_0, x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ and $t_0, t_1, t_2, ... t_n$ where $t_{i+1}-t_i =\Delta t $.

I'm interested in the improved efficiency for large data sets, if it is possible to simplify linear regression in this context.

Edit: I editet the title since *equispaced* is an important property.

Comment: It is likely won't do you a whole lot of good. All you gain are closed formulas for the moments of $t$: the mean is $n(\Delta t)/2$ and the variance is $((n+1)^2-1)(\Delta t)^2/12$. You still have to compute moments of the dependent variable $y$ as well as the covariance of $t$ and $y$. And for rolling regressions, which are updated quickly in constant time, even those formulas accomplish nothing. The only situation I have seen that benefits is where [calculations are limited by software (in)capabilities or there are a huge number of dependent variables](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65841).

Answer (score 5):

In fact in linear regression it's already assumed that the predictor variable (IV) has no error.

If not for that, you'd have [errors-in-variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) regression (though it has various other names). OLS is biased in this case.

So there's no opportunity for efficiency when you impose a condition that's already assumed.

There is some opportunity for some efficiency gain because the $t$'s are equispaced.

However, if you need to refit these models each time a new data point arrives, then there are larger opportunities for gain.

A warning, too, about fitting regression to time series; it [must be done with care](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133155/how-to-use-pearson-correlation-correctly-with-time-series/133171#133171).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me! As it happens the refit you've spoken of when a new data point arrives is of great interest - could you elaborate or point me to a relevant source?

Comment: Search our site for [rolling regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rolling+regression).