# In prewhitening, should we develop an ARIMA(p,q,d) for X but use only ARI(p,q) as the filter?

Tags: time-series, arima, cross-correlation, filter

According to the answer in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221072/why-is-prewhitening-important) by IrishStat, the reason that you pre-whiten X is to identify a filter that can transform Y and X into y and x where x is white noise.

Assume that X is following ARIMA(p, q, d):

$\left( 1 - \sum_{i=1}^p \phi_i L^i \right) (1-L)^d X_t = \left( 1 + \sum_{i=1}^q \theta_i L^i \right) \varepsilon_t $

The L.H.S. is the filter of ARI(p, q) and the R.H.S is a linear combination of i.i.d. white noise, which should also be a white noise. So by applying the filter of ARI(p, q), we can then achieve the objective - transform X into white noise. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: *a linear combination of i.i.d. white noise <...> should also be a white noise* – no. An MA process is autocorrelated. You are combining a given white noise process with its lags, so they are dependent. (A combination of independent white noise processes would remain white noise.)

Comment: @RichardHardy You are right. If x is still autocorrelated, the CCF between y and x still can’t enjoy the cut-off property. Then what is the filter for X with moving averaging component?

Comment: I don't know much about filters.