# when fitting a regression model to a time-series, can I use lagged values of the time-series itself?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, autoregressive, lags

I'm fitting a regression model $y_t$ to a time series $x_t$ (not a dynamic model involving ARMA terms!). I saw that [useful predictors](https://otexts.com/fpp2/useful-predictors.html) to put in my model are $t$, seasonality variables and lagged values of other time-series that are affecting my time-series.

question: why don't they mention the time series lagged variables themselves $x_{t-1}$, $x_{t-2}$? this is different than a dynamic regression model that uses $y_{t-1}$ or $\epsilon_{t-1}$, but sounds so simple and useful...

Comment: if you use a lagged variable of $y_t$ itself then that often has the same effect as including lagged $x_t$'s. Check out lagged dependent variable models or autoregressive distributed lag models for more details.

Comment: what you need to do is to investigate transfer function models (a.k.a dynamic regression) and perhaps read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221072/why-is-prewhitening-important/305634#305634