# What is a suitable way to reveal correlation between these two signals?

Tags: correlation, signal-processing

I have two time-domain data signals which look like the following:

[image]

I know that variations in $x$ are able to induce variations in signal $y$, and would like to be able to show that "*yes, x is correlated with y*". I am looking for some advice on what would be a good method to use to analyse such signals.

Pearson coefficients don't work directly because the changes in $y$ are not linear with $x$. Instead, for these signals, a change in $x$ leads to *oscillations* in $y$ - and the faster rate of change in $x$ the greater the amplitude and frequency of those oscillations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Calculate the Envelope

The envelope $y(t)$ captures the instantaneous power of the oscillations (see the plot, where the envelope is in red), which I think is what you're looking for. The wiki page on the [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal) is a good place to start for this.

[image]

## 2. Be Careful of Autocorrelation

As discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133155/42952),
you can't just correlate two time series.
There's lots of good advice in the linked question,
but the simplest thing you can do is to differentiate the two signals,
$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = x(\tau) - x(\tau-1)$ for all values of $\tau$,
check that there's no autocorrelation in the differentiated signals,
and then correlate them.

Actually, since you're interested in how the rate of change in $x$ predicts oscillatory power in $y$, you need to first calculate the *second* derivate of $X$ (reflecting change in the rate of change, or acceleration/deceleration), and correlate it with the first derivate of envelope of $y$ (reflecting change in power).

In pseudo-code:

```r
ddx = diff(diff(x))
power_y = envelope(y)
d_power_y = diff(power_y)
cor.test(ddx, d_power_y)
```

For the frequency of the oscillations in $y$, you can do the same thing with the [instantaneous frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase_and_frequency).

Comment: Thanks Eoin for your answer. Could you expand a little more. Are you saying to calculate the envelope and then do Pearson with between $x$ and the instantaneous power instead?

Comment: Yes, but before you can do that correlation you need to deal with the autocorrelations in the two time series. How to do that is already well-covered in the linked question, so I won't repeat it all here.

Comment: Thanks - what does autocorrelation in the signal's derivate imply? And briefly, why is it a bad thing that we need to avoid?

Comment: There's a lot of material in the linked question, and this is beyond the scope of your original question, so I won't go into detail. Autocorrelation in the derivative means that the change at time $t$ is correlated with the change at time $t+1$. This is true of any time series that isn't a straight line or a random walk. This is bad because a standard correlation test assumes individual pairs of data points are independent (not autocorrelated), so running it on autocorrelated data gives your spurious results (again, see the linked question).

Comment: I see. But don't we also have to check for autocorrelation in the value itself? Why only the derivative?

Comment: You have to check for autocorrelation in whatever values you're inputting into the correlation test.