# cointegration and correlation

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, cointegration

In the following [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/does-correlation-assume-stationarity-of-data?lq=1) it was shown by mpiktas that the sample correlation  of two I(1) series converge to a random variable. On the other, given two cointegrated I(1) variables the OLS estimator is super-consistent.
How this two facts settle down together using the following relation between the OLS estimator $\hat {\beta}$ and the correlation?

$\hat {\beta} = {\rm cor}(Y_i, X_i) \cdot \frac{ {\rm SD}(Y_i) }{ {\rm SD}(X_i) }$

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicitly, @mpiktas has assumed that there is no cointegration among his two random walks, as they are not of reduced rank. Borrwing his statements

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{t=1}^TX_t^2=\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{1}{T}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\sum_{s=1}^tU_t\right)^2\to \int_0^1M_{1s}^2ds,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{t=1}^TY_t^2\to \int_0^1M_{2s}^2ds
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{t=1}^TX_tY_t\to \int_0^1M_{1s}M_{2s}ds
\end{align}
as well as
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}\to \frac{\int_0^1M_{1s}M_{2s}ds}{\sqrt{\int_0^1M_{1s}^2ds\int_0^1M_{2s}^2ds}}
\end{align}
in distribution as $T\to \infty$, we obtain from your relationship between correlation and the OLSE that
\begin{align}
\hat\beta&\to\frac{\int_0^1M_{1s}M_{2s}ds}{\sqrt{\int_0^1M_{1s}^2ds\int_0^1M_{2s}^2ds}}\frac{\sqrt{\int_0^1M_{2s}^2ds}}{\sqrt{\int_0^1M_{1s}^2ds}}\\&=\frac{\int_0^1M_{1s}M_{2s}ds}{\int_0^1M_{1s}^2ds}
\end{align}
This is (for the special case of no constant in the regression and unit error variances assumed here) precisely the spurios regression distribution of the OLS estimator when regressing two *independent* random walks onto each other derived by [Phillips (Journal of Econometrics 1986, Theorem 1a)](https://ideas.repec.org/p/cwl/cwldpp/757.html).

You would get a fundamentally different result of course if the two random walks were *cointegrated*, in which case, as you point out,
$$
\hat\beta-\beta=\mathcal{O}_p(T^{-1})$$
But this would, as alluded to above, require a reduced-rank assumption in the Vector-error correction representation
$$
\Delta Z_t=\Pi Z_{t-1}+u_t
$$
where $Z_t:=(Y_t,X_t)'$. That is, it would need to be possible to decompose $\Pi=\alpha\beta'$, two vectors, where $\alpha$ gives you the speed of adjustment and $\beta$ the cointegration vector.

In the above example with two independent random walks, we may however write 
$$
Z_t=IZ_{t-1}+u_t
$$
and hence
$$
\Delta Z_t=u_t
$$
so that $\Pi$ does not have reduced rank 1. (The above generalizes to $K$ variables of course, where it is needed for cointegration that $0<rank(\Pi)<K$.)

Comment: Thanks! , where the rank assumption comes in the calculation?

Comment: I made an edit.